# Jtable with Column and Row header using NetBeans GUI builder

Tags: swing, netbeans, jtable

I want my Jtable like this

```
        |Column1          |Column2          |Column3
Row1    |_________________|_________________|_______________
Row2    |_________________|_________________|_______________
Row3    |_________________|_________________|_______________
```

Comment: Column and row header at same time ? please more explanation

Comment: Yeah at same time In netbeans  it has Column header but i want column and row header at same time

Comment: Header either a row or a column what your concept exactly  Do you want to drop column titles?

Comment: No i want both column and row headers

Comment: Are you referring to row Numbers?

Comment: What is the point of having row titles? Just specify the row in the first column. If you have different row header and row columns, it kinda defeats the purpose of a table, and seems more like a matrix

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the row header view of the scroll panel:

```
scrollPane.setRowHeaderView( ... );
```

For example, check out the [Row Number Table](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/18/row-number-table/), which will add a JTable component that displays row numbers.